# How to get the lestest data per group in using my SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Query:

```
SELECT l.id, l.userid, l.checktime, l.SN, u.name, u.badgenumber
FROM kio_checkinout l
LEFT JOIN userinfo u ON l.userid = u.userid
GROUP BY l.userid DESC
```

i need show the data first order by id descending and then group by userid (latest user id) value.

i am trying this sql query but i can not get the data as i need to show.

Comment: I guess you are confusing `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT l.id, l.userid, l.checktime, l.SN, u.name, u.badgenumber
FROM kio_checkinout l
LEFT JOIN userinfo u ON l.userid = u.userid
GROUP BY l.userid 
ORDER BY l.id DESC
```

Comment: @Scottzozer: What do you mean? Am I missing something?

Comment: we have the same answer hahaah

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT l.userid, GROUP_CONCAT(l.checktime,'-',l.checktype), u.name, u.badgenumber
FROM kio_checkinout l
LEFT JOIN userinfo u ON l.userid = u.userid
GROUP BY l.userid
ORDER BY l.id DESC
```

Comment: i have checked, i got this result using my query. but i dont want to repet the user id like 148 in below example:
id  userid    checktime               SN  name  
1223  148  2014-04-29 11:00:00  0455133500061  Vrushali 1222  149  2014-04-29 10:30:00  0455133500061  Sanjivani 1221  148  2014-04-29 10:00:00  0455133500061  Vrushali 1220  7  2014-04-28 20:49:27  0455133500061  Vivek 1219  5  2014-04-28 20:38:09  0455133500061     
1218  13  2014-04-28 20:21:10  0455133500061     
1217  8  2014-04-28 20:19:25  0455133500061     
1216  6  2014-04-28 20:14:29  0455133500061

Comment: Ok well I do not know what this is suppose to be grouped by then :(

Comment: sounds like you need to just straight query the DB without grouping because you want single item tuples

Comment: i have checked, i got this result using my query. but i dont want to repet the user id like 148 in below example:
id  userid    checktime               SN  name  
-------------------------
1223  148  2014-04-29 11:00:00  0455133500061  Vrushali 1222  149  2014-04-29 10:30:00  0455133500061  Sanjivani 1221  148  2014-04-29 10:00:00  0455133500061  Vrushali 1220  7  2014-04-28 20:49:27  0455133500061  Vivek 1219  5  2014-04-28 20:38:09  0455133500061     
1218  13  2014-04-28 20:21:10  0455133500061     
1217  8  2014-04-28 20:19:25  0455133500061     
1216  6  2014-04-28 20:14:29  0455133500061

Comment: ok so you need just the most current? or you still want multiple rows combined

Comment: i jst want to show multiple rows but most recent will be appear at the top means DESC and the user id name will be uique

Comment: just ORDER BY userid, id DESC

Comment: no it dint work bu ti have used groupby Date(l.checktime) order by l.id DESC, it will group the uniqu date from the checktim (timestamp) and by id desc will get latest id.

Comment: But Thanks alot Friends for Replying me, and suggest me some ideas to resolve this. :)